# How can d3.js list the columns in a specified order?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a javascript object **data**:

```
[
  { 'sex': 'male', 'risk': '0.04', 'age_group': 'old' },
  { 'sex': 'female', 'risk': '0.03', 'age_group': 'young' },
  { 'sex': 'male', 'risk': '0.12', 'age_group': 'old' },
  { 'sex': 'female', 'risk': '0.04', 'age_group': 'old' },
]
```

And I also have an array which is used to specify the order of columns called **metadata**:

```
['sex', 'age_group', 'risk']
```

When using d3.js to visualize the data(currently I am using a table), I need to put them in the right order according to **metadata**.

Below is the code I am using to generate the table, without ordering the columns.

```
    var table = d3.select("#visualization_table");
    table.append("thead");
    table.append("tbody");

    var thead = d3.select("thead")
        .selectAll("th")
        .data(metadata)
        .enter()
        .append("th")
        .text(function(d) { return d });
    var tr = d3.select("tbody").selectAll("tr")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("tr");
    var td = tr.selectAll("td")
        .data(function(d) {return d3.values(d)})
        .enter()
        .append("td")
        .text(function(d) {return d});
```

But the order will be like, 'sex', 'risk', 'age_group', while what I want is 'sex', 'age_group', 'risk'. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by explicitly constructing the object in the nested `.data()` call, using `metadata`:

```
.data(function(d) {
  return metadata.map(function(m) { return d[m]; });
})
```

Complete demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ud123e6k/).